# What port to ping on windows machine to check if it is online?

Tags: networking, php, ping

As the question says, I'm using this PHP function to check if an IP address on specific port is answering.

```
function ping($host) {

    $port = 5900;  //RealVNC default port
    $waitTimeoutInSeconds = 0.01;

    if ($fp = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errCode, $errStr,$waitTimeoutInSeconds)) {
        fclose($fp);
        echo '<img src="online.png"> ';
    } else {

        echo '<img src="offline.png"> ';
    }
}
```

Is there any default port on windows (7,8,10) that could be "pinged" by this script to check if it is reachable without enabling or installing anything? - I want to check status of 500 PCs in my network.

Comment: why not "ping" *host* instead of "ping" *port*? ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ref: [PHP: socket_create - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php)

```
<?PHP
        function ping($host, $timeout = 1) {
                /* ICMP ping packet with a pre-calculated checksum */
                $package = "\x08\x00\x7d\x4b\x00\x00\x00\x00PingHost";
                $socket  = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 1);
                socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec' => $timeout, 'usec' => 0));
                socket_connect($socket, $host, null);

                $ts = microtime(true);
                socket_send($socket, $package, strLen($package), 0);
                if (socket_read($socket, 255))
                        $result = microtime(true) - $ts;
                else    $result = false;
                socket_close($socket);

                return $result;
        }
?>
```

Comment: this code gives me errors socket_set_option() expects parameter 1 to be resource and so on for each function

Comment: code is 11 years old, it may not work due to recent changes in php. code is mainly for reference (not for you to run it in your environment by copy and pasting it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use find a free IP scanner if you're on Windows environment or you can use nmap on Linux environments to run a full scan of a given network id.

The next command using nmap:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.2.1/24
```

Will display all the online clients on the 192.168.2.x network.

Here's a link to a php ip scanner script:
https://gist.github.com/blazeeboy/808796

Nmap usually comes by default with Linux operating system unless it's a minimal installation.

Comment: unfortunately i need to do this with php

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I can, I'm running my own server. I will look at your link:)